# What's the probability of 4th passenger carrying a backpack?

Tags: probability

There are 12 seats for passengers on a minibus. The probability of a passenger carrying a backpack is 0.65 independent of all other passengers. Passengers get on to an empty minibus, find the probability that the 4th passenger who gets onto the minibus will be the first to carry the backpack?

What I did:

$0.35^3 \times .65 \times 7(0.65+0.35)=0.195$

But the answer to the question is just $0.35^3\times .65$

How did they assume that the 4th passenger was the last one to get on to the minibus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not putting $7$ in the correct place.
If you want, you could write
$$0.35^3 \times 0.65 \times (0.65+0.35)^7=0.35^3 \times 0.65$$

But you really do not care about what happens after the $4th$ passenger.

Comment: Oh god!!!! How can I do that :'( XD thanks man :D ill accept it as soon as the time expires

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui You are welcome!  Thx!